# How to unit test a C# library that runs PowerShell scripts

Tags: c#, powershell, unit-testing, pester

I have a C# library that runs a couple of PowerShell scripts to manipulate Windows Hypervisor. (e.g. turning VM on and off, create a VM with vhds, getting switches and etc.) It's hard to mock the environment and control the output of the scripts. Scripts for checking/validating stuff could be easier, but the scripts for operational purpose could be a headache because most of these methods could be irreversible.

I found a good unit test framework Pester for PowerShell. But my code consist a great amount of C# code. Is there any good way to handle this unit test problem gracefully?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds to me like the "unit" you're aiming to test actually consists of multiple units - C# unit(s) as well as PS unit(s). Wouldn't the solution be to unit test those separately?

Comment: @Xerillio That's a good point. For the C# code, it's a platform-like library which will execute different powershell scripts in a more organized way. It would be great if there's a way to mock and test both side together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several points to make here:

1. When the code you test does multiple things (units) it is, by definition, an integration test, since it tests the *integration* of multiple units (the comment of @Xerillio).
2. When the code you tests interacts with infrastructure (file system, database, in your case `Powershell` and VM's etc.), it is, by definition, an integration test.

You could try to extract small amounts of code in seperate functions in `C#` and unit test those, giving you certainty those work and do the same in `Powershell` (using Pester). But the real question is; what do you want to achieve? I would assume you want to be sure you're application works now and keeps working in the future (does not regress), in which case you could look more into a more *end to end* approach to testing.

- Find the most outer point of your application with what you can interact from a test, so you test the biggest part of the stack you can.
- Check which parts you *can* automatically test without causing havoc (you mention "irreversible methods")
- Use a unit test framework for setting up the tests in `C#` (like `xUnit`) expressing clear `Setup` and `Teardown` phases that, respectively, setup everything needed before a test and clean up after a test (keep in mind that tests might run parallel by default and this doesn't go well with shared resources on the file system etc.)

This avoids having to rewrite code *just* because you [want to *unit test* it](https://dhh.dk/2014/test-induced-design-damage.html). On the other hand, extracting pure units makes testing those specific units way easier.